# Meaning of visibility Flags

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello!

I'd like to see the endpoints of laserscanner in a camera to simulate a line laser attached to my robot. The laser is however only visible in the gazebo-GUI, but not in a simulated camera image.

I had a look around and found the LaserVisual.cc ( https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/439c127c6f494d8208b082c8832610ea2f67ce8c/gazebo/rendering/LaserVisual.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default ) which looks as if it is responsible for drawing the visualization of the laser scan.

My main finding was this line

```
this->SetVisibilityFlags(GZ_VISIBILITY_GUI);
```

that looks as if it is used to select who can see this visualization. Before I start to recompile the whole gazebo, I'd like to ask if it would be enough to set this flag to `GZ_VISIBILITY_ALL` to get the cameras to see the laser visualization.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/10108/meaning-of-visibility-flags/) by [NikolasE](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1619/nikolase/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The short answer is that should work. For a reference, [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/439c127c6f494d8208b082c8832610ea2f67ce8c/gazebo/rendering/Camera.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Camera.cc-1333) is the visibility mask for cameras:

```
this->viewport->setVisibilityMask(GZ_VISIBILITY_ALL &
    ~(GZ_VISIBILITY_GUI | GZ_VISIBILITY_SELECTABLE));
```

You could also try to change the visibility mask of your camera instead of the flags for the visual.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NikolasE](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1619/nikolase/) on 2015-10-13**:
Thanks! Is it possible to change the mask of the camera or the laser via parameters? Or do I really have to create my own plugin?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-10-13**:
I think you'll need to create a plugin.